# How to pass value from javascript to php using address bar

Tags: php, javascript, blackberry

I have .js and .php files and html pages. I am including js files in html files and php files in js files.

I want to pass 'cat' value from js file to php file using address bar when I go to this page;

> /demo/convert.html?cat=volume

But I have no idea how to do this.

By the way, this is a blacberry project and I am not sure if I can use address bar to pass value. Any idea is welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Test this sample code with an URL like :
http://sputnick-area.net/test/index.php?foobar=works_as_a_charm

```
<?php

$var = $_GET['foobar'];

echo <<<EOF
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
demo of using PHP GET variable in Javascript :
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("$var");
</script>
</body>
</html>
EOF

?>
```

**Edit** :

if you'd like to handle GET variables from within JavaScript, consider the following HTML + JavaScript sample : http://sputnick-area.net/test/index.html?foobar=works_as_a_charm

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var vars = [], hash;
var hashes = window.location.href.slice(
    window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1
).split('&');

for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
    hash = hashes[i].split('=');
    vars.push(hash[0]);
    vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
}

alert(vars['foobar']);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is it possible to use this in an HTML file, not a Php file ?

Comment: No, HTML can't handle POST/GET variables.

Comment: so there is no solution for HTML file, bcs my structure consists of HTML, php and js. Php is for making connection to db, and js for bridge between php and html, and I am using jquery mobile in html file. I am not sure if I can use php files for pages in Blackberry.

Comment: it is alerting 'cat' nat the value, 'volume'. I dont need the variable name I need the value. (:'volume'

Comment: assuming your not trying to run the php script on the blackberry there should be no issue using it on the blackberry as its no different to a regular html page.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can.  When your JS function is called, you would have to do something like this:

```
function someFunction(someParameters) {
    //Do whatever you need to do
    window.location = "/demo/convert.html?variableName=" + variable;
}
```

This will cause a page reload with the new variable accessible through PHP in the `$_GET` array.  For example:

```
<?php
$name = $_GET['variableName'];
if(length($name) < 3) {
    echo "That is a short name!";
}
?>
```

A page reload (used here), is necessary to send value to PHP as it is run server side.  Your only other solution would be to use AJAX and load page content dynamically.  This, however, would be the simplest solution.

EDIT:

```
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
}

var urlvariable = getUrlVars()['variableName'];
```

Comment: It would appear sputnick and I interrupted the question exactly opposite.  My example shows how to pass from JS to PHP.  His is a perfect example of passing from PHP to JS.

Comment: I didn't say it :) I want to pass value from js to Php.

Comment: Are you files hosted somewhere?  For example, are you just looking at this in a web browser or web container within an app?

Comment: but to use window.location = "/demo/convert.html?variableName=" + variable I have to know what is the value of variable. Bcs it ll be in the address page.

Comment: my files are in local and I am using web browser, Austin

Comment: I'm not certain we are addressing the exact issue.  What exactly is the data flow?

Comment: my structure consists of HTML, php and js. Php is for making connection to db, and js for bridge between php and html, and I am using jquery mobile in html file. I have to use html files bcs as far as I know, in blacberry, I have to have an index html.

Comment: I would just chat with you, but I don't have enough rep yet.  For JS to access variables in the url string, see the edit to my original answer.